# Instant App isn't working in release (Instant app launch failed for an unknown reason (getInstantAppPreLaunchInfo failed))

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-instant-apps

When I click on the link Instant App launcher appears but after it navigates to web version. (IA in production release in Google Play).

Debug version works perfectly.

My manifests file exactly the same as with google sample. (With my links and site)

[App link](https://www.buildstacks.com/cards/533/)

I saw logs and find these lines:

> com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor D/Supervisor: UrlHandler
>   starting com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor D/AutoManageHelper:
>   starting AutoManage for client 0 false null
>   com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor D/AutoManageHelper: onStart
>   true {0=com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzi$zza@d12b8e9}
>   com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor E/OptInDirector: Instant app
>   launch failed for an unknown reason (getInstantAppPreLaunchInfo failed
>   - check previous logcat) com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor E/Supervisor: Opt-in aborted.
>   com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor I/PlayCommon: [38684]
>   PlayEventLogger.uploadEventsImpl: Preparing logs for uploading
>   com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor W/PlayCommon: [38684]
>   PlayEventLogger.getAuthToken: No account for auth token provided
>   com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor I/PlayCommon: [38684]
>   PlayEventLogger.uploadLog: Connecting to server:
>   https://play.googleapis.com/play/log?format=raw&proto_v2=true 10-27
>   com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor
>   I/PlayCommon: [38684] PlayEventLogger.handleResponse: Successfully
>   uploaded logs. com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor I/PlayCommon:
>   [38684] PlayEventLogger.uploadEventsImpl: Preparing logs for uploading
>   com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor I/PlayCommon: [38684]
>   PlayEventLogger.uploadEventsImpl: No file ready to send
>   com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor D/Supervisor: Force showing
>   the loadscreen because the 400 ms deadline is up.
>   com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor D/Supervisor: UrlHandler
>   stopping

I think error appears here:

> Instant app launch failed for an unknown reason (Instant app launch
>   failed for an unknown reason (getInstantAppPreLaunchInfo failed -
>   check previous logcat)failed - check previous logcat)
>
> Opt-in aborted.

Comment: Do you use Proguard?
Do you have separate AndroidManifest.xml files for release and debug?
Do you use different sign configs for release and debug?

Comment: @deadmoto Yes, I use proguard. 
I have only one Manifest. (for each module). 
Yes, I sign debug with standard key and create my own storage for release

Comment: Well, try to disable Proguard for release and see if that helps.
Also, try it out on different versions of Android as the Instant Apps runtime has not been stabilized yet.

Comment: I just tested your instant app and didn’t see any issues. Did you change something like disabling Proguard? If yes, this could be what you are looking for: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65710224

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround for this issue is to configure a massive “-keep” proguard for each feature module.

To find out what classes to keep when you configure your proguard, please perform the following:

1. add “-whyareyoukeeping class **” to your app/proguard-rules.pro (installed-app module)
2. set the installed-app’s minifyEnabled to true
3. build the installed-app, then the Gradle Console will contain a list of information on which classes it kept or not
4. copy that portion to some editor so you can edit it
5. for every class that’s noted with either a “**is kept**” or “**is a library**”, that will be a class to keep, ie. “-`keep class some.package.class {*;}`”
   a. you should also be able to do this at the member-level for further optimization
6. after you’ve compiled the list of these keeps, add them to each of your feature’s proguard-rules.pro
7. you may or may not need to verify that base/proguard-rules.pro uses "-dontobfuscate" (or propagate obfuscation maps downstream to features somehow)

Now you can build your instant-app with minifyEnabled true.

Please be aware of step-5, it could be a challenge to compile, depending on how good your editor is. One way the engineer demonstrated was using the AWK command to replace text:
- awk '/^[^ ]/ { cls=$1 } /is (kept|a library)/ { print "-keep class " cls " {*;}" }'

[For more detail and update can you check here.](https://medium.com/google-developers/enabling-proguard-in-an-android-instant-app-fbd4fc014518)